# PHP equivalent for a python decorator?

Tags: php, python, function, decorator, wrapper

I want to be able to wrap a PHP function by another function, but leaving its original name/parameter list intact.

For instance:

```
function A() {
    print "inside A()\n";
}

function Wrap_A() {
    print "Calling A()\n";
    A();
    print "Finished calling A()\n";
}

// <--- Do some magic here (effectively "A = Wrap_A")

A();
```

Output:

```
Calling A()
inside A()
Finished calling A()
```

Comment: Your example of Wrap_A is a little misleading to somebody who doesn't already know how Python decorator's work, since your implementation of Wrap_A explicitly references A. The idea of a decorator is that you can decorate any function with it, but in your example you clearly couldn't use `Wrap_A` to wrap some other function `B`. Would you mind if I edited your question to make it a more accurate representation of what function decoration is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently [runkit](http://php.net/runkit) might [help you](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php).

Also, you can always do this the OO way. Put the original fun in a class, and the decorator into an extended class. Instantiate and go.

Comment: How would you use it as easily and generically as in python - here you add the decorate just above the function definition (similar constructs seen in .NET and Java).

Comment: The links in this answer are now broken.

Comment: I believe they should now be https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit7.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit7-function-redefine.php respectively

Answer (score 9):

Here is my method of mimicking decorators from python in php.

```
function call_decorator ($decorator, $function, $args, $kwargs) {

    // Call the decorator and pass the function to it
    $decorator($function, $args, $kwargs);
}

function testing ($args, $kwargs) {
    echo PHP_EOL . 'test 1234' . PHP_EOL;
}

function wrap_testing ($func, $args, $kwargs) {

    // Before call on passed function
    echo 'Before testing';

    // Call the passed function
    $func($args, $kwargs);

    // After call on passed function
    echo 'After testing';
}

// Run test
call_decorator('wrap_testing', 'testing');
```

Output:

```
Before testing
testing 1234
After testing
```

With this implementation you can also do something like this with an anonymous function:

```
// Run new test
call_decorator('wrap_testing', function($args, $kwargs) {
    echo PHP_EOL . 'Hello!' . PHP_EOL;
});
```

Output:

```
Before testing
Hello!
After testing
```

And lastly you can even do something like this, if you are so inclined.

```
// Run test
call_decorator(function ($func, $args, $kwargs) {
    echo 'Hello ';
    $func($args, $kwargs);
}, function($args, $kwargs) {
    echo 'World!';
});
```

Output:

```
Hello World!
```

With this construction above, you can pass variables to the inner function or wrapper, if need be. Here is that implementation with an anonymous inner function:

```
$test_val = 'I am accessible!';

call_decorator('wrap_testing', function($args, $kwargs){
    echo $args[0];
}, array($test_val));
```

It will work exactly the same without an anonymous function:

```
function test ($args, $kwargs) {
    echo $kwargs['test'];
}

$test_var = 'Hello again!';

call_decorator('wrap_testing', 'test', array(), array('test' => $test_var));
```

Lastly, if you need to modify the variable inside either the wrapper or the wrappie, you just need to pass the variable by reference.

Without reference:

```
$test_var = 'testing this';
call_decorator(function($func, $args, $kwargs) {
    $func($args, $kwargs);
}, function($args, $kwargs) {
    $args[0] = 'I changed!';
}, array($test_var));
```

Output:

```
testing this
```

With reference:

```
$test_var = 'testing this';
call_decorator(function($func, $args, $kwargs) {
    $func($args, $kwargs);
}, function($args, $kwargs) {
    $args[0] = 'I changed!';

// Reference the variable here
}, array(&$test_var));
```

Output:

```
I changed!
```

That is all I have for now, it is a pretty useful in a lot of cases, and you can even wrap them multiple times if you want to.

Comment: `$kwargs`? that doesnt exist in php.

Comment: It does if you write code to support it? kwargs in terms of syntax is no different than an array of key value pairs in php.

Comment: This approach fails if the function call is out of your control, for example in test scripts called by PHPunit.

Comment: @Sebastian can you provide more context for this?
If you are calling a function or method that is not within the current scope, then that wouldn't work regardless of how you want to call it. My answer was from a naive perspective and is not how I would solve this today.

Comment: PHPUnit calls all `public function test*` on itself. I'd like to add a Python-like `@decorator` preparing and cleaning up things for each test. I can't change PHPUnit for calling my `call_decator` function.

Answer (score 3):

maybe you’re looking for [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array):

```
function wrapA() {
  $args = func_get_args();
  return call_user_func_array('A', $args);
}
```

since PHP 5.3 you could even say:

```
return call_user_func_array('A', func_get_args());
```

---

after you’ve edited your question i would say, no, this is not possible, but there are some ways, see this question: [how to implement a decorator in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948443/how-to-implement-a-decorator-in-php)

Comment: This is not at all related to what I'm looking for. I edited my question to add clarification.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Aspect Oriented Programming**. But you need some framework that support AOP.

For example **Symfony**. 
This is one of implementations of AOP for php 
https://github.com/goaop/goaop-symfony-bundle

There is also the Nette Framework (I use [this one](https://github.com/Kdyby/Aop))

In principle it works like this: let's say you want to throw an exception if user is not logged in and tries to access some method.

This is just *"fictive"* code to show how it works.

You have some aspect method like this:

```
/** @AroundMethod(annotataion="isUserLogged()") */
public function checkUser(Method $method) {
    if ($this->user->isLogged()) {
        return $method->call();
    } else {
        throw new \Exception('User must be logged');
    }
}
```

And then you can use the annotation `@isUserLogged` in your services which will be probably registered in some DI container.

```
/**
 * @isUserLogged()
 */
public function changeUserInfo() {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with functions in PHP.  In other dynamic languages, such as Perl and Ruby, you can redefine previously defined functions, but PHP throws a fatal error when you attempt to do so.

In 5.3, you can create an [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and store it in a variable:

```
<?php
    $my_function = function($args, ...) { ... };
    $copy_of_my_function = $my_function;
    $my_function = function($arg, ...) { /* Do something with the copy */ };
?>
```

Alternatively, you can use the traditional decorator pattern and/or a factory and work with classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation of python decorators by using php attributes

```
use Sagittaracc\PhpPythonDecorator\Decorator;

class Calc
{
    use Decorator;

    #[Timer]
    function sum($a, $b)
    {
        sleep(1);
        return $a + $b;
    }
}
```

```
#[Attribute]
class Timer
{
    public function main($func, ...$args)
    {
        $time_start = microtime(true);

        $result = $func($args);

        $time_end = microtime(true);

        return sprintf(
            "Total execution: %f; Result: %d",
            $time_end - $time_start,
            $result
        );
    }
}
```

You can check it out here - https://github.com/sagittaracc/php-python-decorator