# Function decorator(Python) like behaviour in PHP

Tags: php, python, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP equivalent for a python decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425303/php-equivalent-for-a-python-decorator)

I'd like to achieve the same behaviour in PHP, that I can do with Python decorators.

So instead of writing my class like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public function myFunc($param1, $param2, $param3)
    {
        $param1 = $param1 * 2;
        $param1 = $param1 * 2;
        $param1 = $param1 * 2;
        echo $param1.$param2.$param3;
    }
}
```

I want to do it like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    @some_magic_multiplier_decorator
    public function myFunc($param1, $param2, $param3)
    {
        echo $param1.$param2.$param3;
    }
}
```

where both classes do the same.

Is this possible in PHP?

Thanks

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? PHP doesn't support this feature directly, but it does support similarly crazy things.

Comment: I want to filter/modify the contents of every function parameter, in every function

Comment: Question was closed, so I cannot provide an answer. But you could do this at the top of every function: `list($a, $b, $c) = modify(func_get_args());`, where `modify` is a function that filters and returns an array in the same order. It sounds like a bad hack, but it's the closest you are going to get to the python functionality.