# Logging all Soap request and responses in PHP

Tags: php, soap

Does anyone know how to log all request and responses with the builtin SoapClient in PHP? I could in fact manually log everything with `SoapClient::__getLastRequest()` and `SoapClient::__getLastResponse()` But we have that much soap requests in our system that i'm looking other possibilities.

Note: i'm using wsdl mode so using a method that tunnels all through to `SoapClient::__soapCall()` isn't an option

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I second Aleksanders and Stefans suggestion but would not subclass SoapClient. Instead I'd wrap the regular SoapClient in a decorator, because logging is not a direct concern of the SoapClient. In addition, the loose coupling lets you easily substitute the SoapClient with a mock in your UnitTests, so you can concentrate on testing the logging functionality. If you only want to log specific calls, you can add some logic that filters requests and responses by $action or anything you see fit.

**Edit** since Stefan suggested to add some code, the decorator would probably look something like this, although I am not sure about the __call() method (see Stefans comments)

```
class SoapClientLogger
{
    protected $soapClient;

    // wrapping the SoapClient instance with the decorator
    public function __construct(SoapClient $client)
    {
        $this->soapClient = $client;
    }

    // Overloading __doRequest with your logging code
    function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) 
    {
         $this->log($request, $location, $action, $version);

         $response = $this->soapClient->__doRequest($request, $location, 
                                                    $action, $version, 
                                                    $one_way);

         $this->log($response, $location, $action, $version);
         return $response;
    }

    public function log($request, $location, $action, $version)
    {
        // here you could add filterings to log only items, e.g.
        if($action === 'foo') {
            // code to log item
        }
    }

    // route all other method calls directly to soapClient
    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        // you could also add method_exists check here
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->soapClient, $method), $args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a decorator is a very good idea. Actually I'd go with a decorator-solution myself if I had to work on the same problem. But I think, the subclassing-solution is a little bit more comprehensible.

Comment: And then there is a PHP problem that disallows the *stacking* of decorators if you're using the method-overloading-feature `__call()` in one of your decorators or in the class to be decorated (`SoapClient` in this case).

Comment: I didnt know there was an issue with __call(). Do you have a link where I can read about it? This would be good to know. Oh, and I added code above.

Comment: What I meant is that you cannot determine if a method is callable when using `__call()`, so calling a non-existing method will always raise a fatal error. In case of decorating the `SoapClient` you could check `is_callable(array($this->soapClient, $method))` and `in_array($method, $this->soapClient-> __getFunctions())`. But this will not allow to stack decorators.

Comment: Forget my remark about the problem (and the stacking of decorators)... It is possible to do the checks I showed above and still be able to stack your decorators. Sorry for all the chaos *g*

Comment: I tried this solution but log method is not called, the call is forwared straight to soapclient

Comment: This solution doesn't work if you want to use WSDL's dynamic methods. I.e. call to `$mySoapClient->MyWsdlMethod()` will not be logged. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3939077/758991) for more info about why it doesn't work. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1729614/758991) for the solution that works (it uses inheritance instead of composition).

Answer (score 10):

I think the better way is to override `SoapClient::__doRequest()` (and not `SoapClient::__soapCall()`) as you'll have direct access to the request- as well as to the response-XML. But the general approach to subclass `SoapClient` should be the way to go.

```
class My_LoggingSoapClient extends SoapClient
{
    // logging methods

    function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) 
    {
        $this->_logRequest($location, $action, $version, $request);
        $response = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
        $this->_logResponse($location, $action, $version, $response);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

From an *OOP-design* / *design pattern* point of view a [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) is obviously the better way to handle this kind of problem - please see [Gordon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729345/logging-all-soap-request-and-responses-in-php/1729640#1729640). But this is a little bit more difficult to implement.

Comment: I guess this is a preferable solution over decorator. As `SoapClient` not really OOP-aish, and it doesn't implement any interfaces, it is really no way to make decorator be compatible with it from the language point of view, if soap client dependency was type-hinted with `\SoapClient`. If you write a library that uses this client yourself, of course, better to wrap it and implement some interface. But if you want to substitute object in an already existing library, that expects an object of type `SoapClient`, decorators won't do (but again, if there are no type-hints you can go with it).

Comment: @sevavietl That's right. Implementing a decorator that is compatible with a `SoapClient` type hint might be problematic (due to the missing interface and the dynamic nature of the `SoapClient` API). Never tried that myself so I cannot judge whether it's possible in general or not.

Comment: This was the only way that worked for me, using wsdl's dynamic methods.

Answer (score 8):

Sorry to revisit such an old post, but I encountered some challenges with the accepted answer's implementation of a decorator that is responsible for the logging of the Soap requests and wanted to share in case anyone else runs into this.

Imagine you set up your instance like the following, using the SoapClientLogger class outlined in the accepted answer.

```
$mySoapClient = new SoapClientLogger(new SoapClient());
```

Presumably any method you call on the SoapClientLogger instance will get passed through the __call() method and executed on the SoapClient. However, typically you make use of a SoapClient by calling the methods generated from the WSDL, like this:

```
$mySoapClient->AddMember($parameters); // AddMember is defined in the WSDL
```

This usage will never hit the SoapClientLogger's _doRequest() method and thus the request will not be logged. Instead AddMember() is routed through $mySoapClient::_call() and then right on down to the SoapClient instance's _doRequest method.

I'm still searching for an elegant solution to this.

Comment: The "elegant solution" is to use inheritance instead of composition as this answer suggests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1729614/758991. People, who accepted/upvoted the "decorator pattern" answer probably do not use WSDL's dynamic methods.

Answer (score 3):

Adressing the issue raised in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3939077/861788 I came with the following solution ([full source](https://github.com/Lc5/Toolbox/tree/master/src/LoggingSoapClient)):

```
<?php

namespace Lc5\Toolbox\LoggingSoapClient;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Class LoggingSoapClient
 *
 * @author Łukasz Krzyszczak <lukasz.krzyszczak@gmail.com>
 */
class LoggingSoapClient
{

    const REQUEST  = 'Request';
    const RESPONSE = 'Response';

    /**
     * @var TraceableSoapClient
     */
    private $soapClient;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @param TraceableSoapClient $soapClient
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(TraceableSoapClient $soapClient, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->soapClient = $soapClient;
        $this->logger     = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $method
     * @param array $arguments
     * @return string
     */
    public function __call($method, array $arguments)
    {
        $result = call_user_func_array([$this->soapClient, $method], $arguments);

        if (!method_exists($this->soapClient, $method) || $method === '__soapCall') {
            $this->logger->info($this->soapClient->__getLastRequest(), ['type' => self::REQUEST]);
            $this->logger->info($this->soapClient->__getLastResponse(), ['type' => self::RESPONSE]);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $request
     * @param string $location
     * @param string $action
     * @param int $version
     * @param int $oneWay
     * @return string
     */
    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $oneWay = 0)
    {
        $response = $this->soapClient->__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $oneWay);

        $this->logger->info($request, ['type' => self::REQUEST]);
        $this->logger->info($response, ['type' => self::RESPONSE]);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
use Lc5\Toolbox\LoggingSoapClient\LoggingSoapClient;
use Lc5\Toolbox\LoggingSoapClient\TraceableSoapClient;
use Lc5\Toolbox\LoggingSoapClient\MessageXmlFormatter;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;

$handler = new StreamHandler('path/to/your.log');
$handler->setFormatter(new MessageXmlFormatter());

$logger = new Logger('soap');
$logger->pushHandler($handler);

$soapClient = new LoggingSoapClient(new TraceableSoapClient('http://example.com'), $logger);
```

SOAP client will then log every request and response using any PSR-3 logger.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
class MySoapClient extends SoapClient
{
    function __soapCall($function_name, $arguments, $options = null, $input_headers = null, &$output_headers = null) 
    {
        $out = parent::__soapCall($function_name, $arguments, $options, $input_headers, $output_headers);

        // log request here...
        // log response here...

        return $out;
    }
}
```

Since SoapClient already sends all requests through __soapCall, you can intercept them by subclassing SoapClient and overriding it. Of course, to make it work you need to also replace every `new SoapClient(...)` in your code with `new MySoapClient(...)`, but that seems like a pretty easy search and replace task.

Comment: This does not work... do you have any insight as to why __soapCall can't be overridden anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old issue but I see bits and pieces and it's difficult to piece it all together.

Expanding on [Stefan Gehrig answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1729614/329338), I ended up having to extend SoapClient in order to be able to use the dynamic methods from the WSDL. Also, out of convenience, this class adds the tracing option directly in the construct.

```
<?php

class SoapClientLogger extends SoapClient
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $provider;

    /**
     * Create the SoapClient instance.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $wsdl
     * @param  array|null  $options
     * @throws SoapFault
     */
    public function __construct(string $wsdl = null, ?array $options = null)
    {
        /**
         * Set trace option to enable logging.
         */
        $options = array_merge($options, [
            'trace' => 1,
        ]);

        parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
    }

    /**
     * Overloading __doRequest method.
     *
     * @param  string  $request
     * @param  string  $location
     * @param  string  $action
     * @param  int  $version
     * @param  null  $one_way
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = NULL): ?string
    {
        $sentAt = now();
        $startTime = microtime(true);
        $response = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);

        $this->log(
            $location,
            $action,
            $version,
            $sentAt,
            number_format(microtime(true) - $startTime, 4),
            parent::__getLastRequestHeaders(),
            parent::__getLastRequest(),
            parent::__getLastResponseHeaders(),
            // Sometimes get last response is null but $response has the body.
            parent::__getLastResponse() ?? $response
        );

        return $response;
    }


    /**
     * Handle logging.
     *
     * @param  string  $location
     * @param  string  $action
     * @param  string  $version
     * @param  Carbon  $sentAt
     * @param  float  $timing
     * @param  string|null  $requestHeaders
     * @param  string|null  $requestBody
     * @param  string|null  $responseHeaders
     * @param  string|null  $responseBody
     */
    protected function log(
        string $location,
        string $action,
        string $version,
        Carbon $sentAt,
        float $timing,
        string $requestHeaders = null,
        string $requestBody = null,
        string $responseHeaders = null,
        string $responseBody = null
    ) {
        // Do logging tasks here.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps provide clarity on possible solutions.

Answer (score -1):

I checked requests and responses with WireShark.