# php class magick function __call doesn't work

Tags: php, class, call

Hello i trying store debug information by using magick class function __call , but nothing store in....

__call

```
function __call($method, $arguments)
{

    $load_functions = array('get', 'insert', 'update', 'delete', 'rawQuery');

    if(in_array($method, $load_functions))
    {

        array_push($this->_debug, microtime(true));

    }

}
```

execute

```
$app->database->setbase('MyBase');
$query = $app->database->get('MEMB_INFO');

$app->database->debug();
```

nothing store into $this->_debug array... $app->database->debug(); return empty array.

Comment: Are you aware that __call function is called only if called function does not exists?

Comment: What's the class you're extending?

Comment: you have to post a complete example which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magic method __call is invoked only for non-existing methods. But I suppose your methods exist.

If you really want to inspect methods calling you can use decorator. It is class that holds instance of original class, has same interface as original class and each method invoke is delegated back to original object. You can add custom debug logic to decorator methods (or use __call and create universal debug decorator). Of course you need inject decorator instance to $app->database. It could be done in many ways depends on your framework and enviroment (prod vs. dev etc.).

Example of what I am thinking - [Logging all Soap request and responses in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729345/logging-all-soap-request-and-responses-in-php)