# NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - php web service

Tags: php, web-services

any wrong for this function ??
NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error

```
private function getWebService() {
    require_once ('lib/nusoap.php');
    $param = array( 'your_name' => 'Monotosh Roy');
    $client = new soapclient('http://192.168.1.100/WebServiceSOAP/server.php');
    $response = $client->call('get_message',$param);
    if($client->fault)
    {
        echo "FAULT: <p>Code: (".$client->faultcode."</p>";
        echo "String: ".$client->faultstring;
    }
    else
    {
        echo $response;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message

> NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error

shows that something is wrong with the network/ connection.
Either from your machine to the local one or from your local server to the soap-interface at:

> http://192.168.1.100/WebServiceSOAP/server.php

Can you access this address from your dev-machine or have a look at the logs of that machine. There should be an occurred error. 
You can also set up an request logging for that machine at 192.168.1.100 so you could reproduce what was sent from your application that caused the 500- error.

[SOAP Request/Response logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729345/logging-all-soap-request-and-responses-in-php)