# Debugging, capturing, and logging XML/SOAP requests for WordPress plugin

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, soap

I have WordPress site with WooCommerce and a UPS shipping calculation plugin installed. Recently client has had issues with discrepancies in calculations and UPS charges. Contacting UPS had them asking for this:

> Your complete XML request and response files associated with the
>   issue. If you are using Web Services, be sure to include the SOAP
>   envelope and the SOAP security header.
>
> You will need to debug your application to obtain the XML/Soap
>   Envelope request and response files.

So the question is this possible without developing a program, or is it even a reasonable request?

Any direction would be helpful. Even a resource that is specific to this platform, that starts from the beginning. (I don't know what a WDSL file is...) I have spent several hours on Google and have come up empty.

I have access to my server at the root level. It is Apache. I can use code snippets if I know where to put them. I have enabled debugging everywhere in the installation I can find.

Comment: What is the plugin?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729345/logging-all-soap-request-and-responses-in-php