# PHP workaround to extend classes of the same name?

Tags: php, oop

I know extending a class with the same name is not possible, but I was curious if anyone knew of a way to load a class then rename it, so i can later extend it with the original name. Hopefully like something below:

```
<?php 
//function to load and rename Class1 to Class2: does something like this exist?
load_and_rename_class('Class1', 'Class2');

//now i can extend the renamed class and use the original name:
class Class1 extends Class2{
}
?>
```

EDIT:
Well, I understand that this would be terrible practice in a basic OOP environment where there are large libraries of class files. But i'm using the CakePHP MVC framework and it would make great sense to be able to extend plugin classes in this way since the framework follows a well established naming convention (Model names, view names, controller names, url routes (http://site.com/users), etc).

As of now, to extend a CakePHP plugin (eg: Users plugin) you have to extend all the model, view, and controller classes each with different names by adding a prefix (like AppUsers) then do some more coding to rename the variable names, then you have to code the renamed url routes, etc. etc. to ultimately get back to a 'Users' name convention.

Since the MVC framework code is well organized it would easily make sense in the code if something like the above is able to be implemented.

Comment: Really __never__ think about something like this again! Its against nearly every good habit

Comment: Even though I don't really get what you're asking I can say it sounds like a bad idea stemming from some fundamental missunderstanding of the technology in question.

Comment: @markus: In short, he wants to _replace_ an existing class with a new one, that should extend the former one. Bad idea, yes.

Comment: Why don't you just rename the class? `class BaseClass_Extended extends BaseClass`?

Comment: "As of now, to extend a CakePHP plugin (eg: Users plugin) you have to ..." and whats the point? Either that, or don't use Cake. "Naming conventions" have a reason and this is not, that one should break fundamental OOP concepts ;)

Comment: @KingCrunch I have to disagree, there are an exhaustive list of reasons to use CakePHP aside from this caveat. The fundamental concepts behind CakePHP's plugins is a great way to create reusable code, and may be worth supersceding orthodox OOP fundamentals in very specific cases as long as it's clear in the code where it happens. If it's easily understandable to extend a class in this way to make coding much simpler then why not?

Comment: I didn't want to say anything against Cake. I don't want to talk too much, thus just short: "and may be worth supersceding orthodox OOP fundamentals" The problem is, that Cake is built on top of this "orthodox PHP fundamentals". I'll promise you, that you _will_ break your application sooner or later, even by thinking about such hacks.

Comment: True "Cake is built on top" of the OOP fundamentals, but what emerged from it is a new set of fundamentals- Plugin fundamentals. The file structures are not vast libraries, they are organized in a way where it would make sense to extend a class of the same name in your application. Also, i feel that this strategy is simply a workaround for PHP 5.2's lack of namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to work out why this would be necessary. I can only think of the following example:

In a context that you have no control over, an object is initialised:

```
// A class you can't change
class ImmutableClass {
    private function __construct() {
        $this->myObject = new AnotherImmutableClass();
    }
}

$immutable = new ImmutableClass();

// And now you want to call a custom, currently non existing method on myObject
// Because for some reason you need the context that this instance provides
$immutable->myObject->yourCustomMethod();
```

And so now you want to add methods to AnotherImmutableClass without editing either Immutable class.

**This is absolutely impossible.**

All you can do from that context is to wrap that object in a decorator, or run a helper function, passing the object.

```
// Helper function
doSomethingToMyObject($immutable->myObject);
// Or decorator method
$myDecoratedObject = new objectDecorator($immutable->myObject);
$myDecoratedObject->doSomethingToMyObject();
```

Sorry if I got the wrong end of the stick.

For more information on decorators see this question:
[how to implement a decorator in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948443/how-to-implement-a-decorator-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

I happen to understand why you would want to do this, and have come up with a way to accomplish what the end goal is.   For everyone else, this is an example of what the author may be dealing with...

Through out a CakePHP application you may have references to helper classes (as an example > $this->Form->input();)

Then at some point you may want to add something to that input() function, but still use the Form class name, because it is through out your application.  At the same time though you don't want to rewrite the entire Form class, and instead just update small pieces of it.  So given that requirement, the way to accomplish it is this...

You do have to copy the existing class out of the Cake core, but you do NOT make any changes to it, and then when ever you upgrade cake you simply make an exact copy to this new directory.  (For example copy lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php to app/View/Helper/CakeFormHelper.php)

You can then add a new file called app/View/Helper/FormHelper.php and have that FormHelper extend CakeFormHelper, ie.

```
App::uses('CakeFormHelper', 'View/Helper');

FormHelper extends CakeFormHelper {
    // over write the individual pieces of the class here
}
```