# Pass a static function of an abstract class as a callback function

Tags: php

Let's say we've implemented a abstract class which holds some tools. For example a mail function:

```
abstract class Tools {
    public static function sendMail () {
        // do some magic mail sending
    }
}
```

Now we have an index.php file, which uses the framework Flight for instance (doesn't mind which framework in particular).

In this index.php we define some routes and assign callback functions to be called if a certain route is requested.

```
Flight::route('POST /mail', Tools::sendMail);
```

If I try this code PHP returns this exception:

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'sendMail'

Is there a way to pass a function like this in PHP?

Comment: Duplicate but i ran out of flags http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655667/passing-static-methods-as-arguments-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`callable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php):

```
public static function route($method, callable $callable)
{
    $callable();
}

Flight::route('POST /mail', function () { Tools::sendMail(); });
```

Comment: This will certainly work but a concern is that this isn't terribly dynamic - this code would need to be copy/pasted in order to reference other static class functions.

Comment: I've gone with `Flight::route('POST /mail', function () { Tools::sendMail(); });`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
[__CLASS__,'MethodName']
```

if the callback is made in the same class or

```
[Class::class,'MethodName']
```

if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass 2 things in order to reference a static class method: The name of the class, and the name of the static function to call

```
//define the method
function callStaticClassMethod($className, $funcName) {
    $className::$funcName();
}

//call the method
callStaticClassMethod('Tools', 'sendMail');
```

I'm not aware of any other way to directly reference a static function.