# how to go one record back in mysqli_query result object

Tags: php, mysql

I know [`mysqli_data_seek`](http://php.net/mysqli-data-seek) let us move at the desired offset, but *how can I use it to go just one step back when a specific criteria met?* I am using `while-loop` for the condition so you can conclude that when the condition will be met the pointer will be on next record. *How can I pull it back just one step?*

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: @CORRUPT tried and succeeded using a counter variable somehow similar method given in answers but just wanted to know that is there any iterator function for this like `prev()`

Comment: No, there are no such build-in methods (i.e. `prev()`, `next()`, `current()` or `rewind()`, like [`iterators`](http://php.net/iterator) has). However, you may extend [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/mysqli-result) class or create a [decorator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948443/how-to-implement-a-decorator-in-php), that can do it. Or simply, create own functions.

Answer (score 1):

*It is not so hard as it seems.*

1. Count fetched offset.
2. When you reach condition go to `offset - 1` and iterate cycle with [`continue`](http://php.net/continue) if needed.

***Example:***

```
$offset = 0;

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

   if($condition && $offset){
        $result->data_seek(--$offset);
        continue;
   }

   $offset++;

   // actions

}
```

Also, I'll quote my comment:

> There are no such build-in methods (i.e. `prev()`, `next()`,
>   `current()` or `rewind()`, like [`iterators`](http://php.net/iterator)
>   has). However, you may extend
>   [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/mysqli-result) class or create a
>   [decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948443/how-to-implement-a-decorator-in-php),
>   that can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
 if($i != 0 && condition){
       mysqli_data_seek($result, $i-1);
 }
$i++;
}
```