# Extending the core CI_Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

According to this [Extending core CI Classes](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html) , I can create a class in my application/core/MY_Protectedcontroller.php as:

```
   //e.g. I want to extend core CI_Controller class.So
   class MY_Protectedcontroller extends CI_Controller{
      function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('permission');
        $this->load->library('authentication');
      }
    }
```

Well as you might discern my objective here..actually I want the auth and perm libraries to be available to all of my controllers thus I can authenticate very easily and programmatically. But when I tried to do:

```
    class User extends MY_Protectedcontroller{
      function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        .....// relevant codes
        .....//relevant codes
      }
    }
```

It says the **"Not Found"** thing.
**Fatal error: Class 'MY_Protectedcontroller' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\damcombd\application\controllers\admin\user.php on line 3**

Comment: Did you use `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';` in `application/config/config.php`?

Comment: @grimv01k Yeah.. I did! Actually it seemed ugly to me and I wanted to change it but didn't for now..So I'm quite aware of that..:)

Comment: Why do you want to it as controller? just for permission and authentication?

Comment: Maybe I'm just not fully comprehending something but is there an issue with autoloading the permission and authentication libraries in the `/application/config/autoload.php` file?

Comment: @kumar_v Well Kumar, you know I need authentication and permission things which I will be required to use in all of my controller functions to check unauthenticated attempts. If I had 30 or 40 controller method does it make sense I write those functions inside all those Controllers? Then why is Object oriented? Why is modularity out there?

Comment: @user2191572 I have given the answer.. the I didn't like the way I solved it.. But the answer is there.. You could check that out.

Comment: What version of CodeIgniter are you using?

Comment: why can't you make it as library and load in autoload.php?

Comment: @kumar_v you can. But they want to do it by extending the controller class which is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: @kumar_v had I made it out from a library I would have been required to write a lot of $this->library->that(); which I dont really like..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to name your class file `MY_Controller.php`, **NOT** `MY_Protectedcontroller.php`.

As you can see in the [user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html), in the System Class list, `MY_Protectedcontroller` is not there. You have to extend an existing class, and you have to name it appropriately for CodeIgniter to find it. In this case, we're extending `Controller`, so you have to name the file `MY_Controller.php` so that CodeIgniter recognizes and finds it (you can change `MY_` in the config as you've found). If we were trying to extend the Input class, we would name the file `MY_Input.php` and so on.

---

Download Codeigniter 2.1.4 and put it somehwere.

Create `MY_Controller.php` and put it in `application/core/MY_Controller.php`:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Protectedcontroller extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Create a controller `test.php` and put it in `controllers/test.php`:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends MY_Protectedcontroller
{
    function index()
    {
        echo "test";
    }
}
```

and visit `http://localhost/ci-2.1.4/index.php/test`

Comment: yeah I've read it.. It says **when u extending** **'Your new class name and filename must be prefixed with MY_ '**. It not necessarily said that the class name has to be Controller followed by MY_. I'm sorry if I've got the point wrong. And I tried as u suggested but it did not work. Does yours work? I think it is..Otherwise you wouldn't be so confident about that! Okay let try once more..

Answer (score 0):

Well just adding require_once made it work..It's something I dont like though. Coz, the Ellislab doc never says that I need to do this thing.. any way this worked for me:

```
    require_once APPPATH.'core/MY_Protectedcontroller.php';
    class User extends MY_Protectedcontroller{
       function __construct(){
         parent::__construct();
         .....// relevant codes
         .....//relevant codes
       }
    }
```

Comment: Well I dont know why I have to require this if the framework were okay..! Am I wrong..? Then why the doc does not say anything about it..?

Comment: You are wrong. There is something else going on. You should not need to do it this way. Please tell us the version of CodeIgniter you are using. Also, please double-check your spelling in the application (case matters).

Comment: @stormdrain version **2.1.4**. If spelling and case were the matter then why did the above worked?

Comment: Because incorrect spelling and case would cause CodeIgniter to not automatically load the class! If you `require` it, then of course it won't matter to CodeIgniter because it won't be loading it.

Comment: @stormdrain I think you have done this before.. So you should be right. But I couldn't find any typos there.. Well you can see the question closely too. If there were typo weren't it there?

Comment: Please see my answer. You have named the class file incorrectly.

Comment: @stormdrain Yes u were right.. But you know what I didnt like this feature at all..! Why should I have to write MY_Controller..while docs don't even mention that stricture..It just mentions vaguely. Any way when I extend I should be able to name my new class anything (if the prefix needed I will forgive that..). This is just weird about CI..I didn't love it either..Thanx any way..

Comment: You can name the class whatever you want - the file name has to be the class you are extending (in this case Controller).

Comment: @stormdrain You right this time too.. Thanx bro..I can see why u have earned a lot of reputation.. Thanx.BTW did u make any wrapper or decorator in CI?

Comment: I got the rep the same way I answered this question -- by searching google and testing -- easy for anyone to do. I have not worked with decorators in php, but -- again thanks to google -- I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/948443/183254

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be targeting some very advanced functionality.

Would you ever consider loading the permission and authentication libraries in the same way that CodeIgniter automatically loads the `/system/core/Input.php` file? This is why you can easily call `$this->input->post();`

If you are willing to mess with the system directory files then I think it should be as simple as finding line #208 in `/system/core/CodeIgniter.php` and make it look like this

```
/* Line 208 starts here
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Load the Input class and sanitize globals
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    $IN =& load_class('Input', 'core');

/* 
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Load the Permission class
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    $PERM =& load_class('Permission', 'libraries/custom');

/* 
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Load the Authentication class
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    $AUTH =& load_class('Authentication', 'libraries/custom');
```

And make sure you place your libraries in the proper directories like so:

```
/system/libraries/custom/Permission.php
/system/libraries/custom/Authentication.php
```

This should now give you global access to `$this->authentication->someFunc();` and `$this->permission->someFunc();`

If you want to find the `load_class()` function then go to line #133 in `/system/core/Common.php` and look for `function &load_class()`

Comment: No, it's as simple as adding the class in `application/core` and extending said class when creating controllers.

Comment: @user2191572 No, I'm not going to pierce in in the core's &load_class function. I would If I needed. My goal is just a base controller class which loads the necessary auth and perm functions for me to use in every classes which are inherited from that base class. So that If when I change, I just make the change in that base class thus nothing affects my numerous controllers(there are a lot of them..u know). Your approach is advanced and good..though I m not opting to do it. Rather I would like to have some wrapper function like Python-Django has like '@login_required' decorator..anything on?

Comment: I am not familiar with Python or Django unfortunately but I just wanted to show the internals of CodeIgniter because its' future is uncertain right now and you might be forced to mess with the `/system` folder in the near future if you come up with more advanced desires. I figured my approach would be un-desireable in terms of best practice but I felt it was important to show it.